# Select where user roles 1 and 2 SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following is what I got right now, which does not work properly because it checks one row for two different values.

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ru ON users.id = ru.user_id
WHERE ru.role_id = 1 AND ru.role_id = 2
```

I would like to select all users that have two rows in roles_users. The one rows role_id should have one and the second should have role_id two.

So select all users that have two rows in the roles_users where one of them has `role_id = 1` and the other has `role_id = 2`.

The above query selects all users that have one row in roles_users that has first one and then two, that's why I get no results and it does not work. So how can I do this right?

Comment: You may have a bigger problem in that you're trying to get `users.id = ru.role_id` - where the userid is equal to their role?

Comment: Wow that is wrong ofcourse i should be ru.user_id..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if somebody decides "Having a single `role_id` = 3 is equivalent"?

Comment: So you want to find all users that have role 1 & 2 OR 3?  That gets uglier, but I'd probably do 2 queries and a UNION, then a GROUP BY on the resultset to eliminate duplicates (e.g. people who have 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: HAVING is basically a where clause that operates after the group by aggregates the data (where clause takes effect before the aggregation).

Comment: @Karem `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ensures that only `id`s with _both_ 1 **and** 2 are selected (assuming no duplicate roles).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just join in on roles_users twice?  Ala:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
INNER JOIN roles_users ru1 ON users.id = ru1.role_id AND ru1.role_id = 1 
INNER JOIN roles_users ru2 ON users.id = ru2.role_id AND ru2.role_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a (distinct) list of the users having the required roles.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT users.{column_list}
FROM users as a
JOIN (SELECT user_id
      FROM roles_users
      WHERE role_id IN (1, 2)
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id) = 2) required_role
  ON required_role.user_id = users.id
```